# ADP.com WorkforceNow integration - c#/JSON/sql integration

Tags: c#, sql, json

I'm trying to get a json object formatted so I can insert it into a few different SQL tables. I get a JSON response from ADP's web services that matches this format:

```
{
  "workers": [
    {
      "associateOID": "string",
      "workerID": {
        "idValue": "string",
        "schemeCode": {
          "codeValue": "string",
          "shortName": "string",
          "longName": "string"
          "..."   
        }
      }
```

I have no issue writing the raw JSON to the console, but I can't figure out how to access the individual properties in the response to manipulate into a SQL database.

Here's my C# that returns the JSON reponse:

```
                        String str = connection.getADPData("/hr/v2/workers?limit=5");
                        Console.WriteLine("\r\nData: {0} ",str);
```

Any insight into how I can take the data returned in str and use it in a SQL insert query is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually asking about?  JSON deseriazation or inserting data into your database?  Please how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: I am looking for "Any insight into how I can take the data returned in str and use it in a SQL insert query"... Thanks.

Comment: Look for "How to parse JSON in .NET." This is a 101 question.

Comment: Tomalak, I am aware of how to deserialize the JSON response. I'm having trouble using the data in the response to insert into a SQL database. I can't figure out how to actually access the properties after deserialization.